# Free a form with a Marker selected makes app crash (MapView)

Tags: android, delphi, android-mapview, delphi-10.1-berlin, c++builder-10.1-berlin

If any marker is selected on a MapView using this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

The app crash right after the form is closed.

But, if using this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
try
MapView1.DisposeOf;
finally
Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
end;
```

The app doesn't crash, but an Access violation message is fired after the form is closed. What may be causing this? There is someway to avoid it?

Best regards

Comment: I don't make much sense of this. You're closing the form (calling `Close`) from the `OnMarkerClick` event of the map control? Or are you calling `Free` from a control event?

Comment: @Victoria The form is being closed by a Button.OnClick event (Form1.Close;) or using the phone Back button.

Comment: Looks like there's a bug in TMapView. Provide a reproducible test case (preferably with an accompanying callstack) and report it, here: https://quality.embarcadero.com

Comment: @Dave Nottage I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Actually I was adding markers to the map in the wrong way. You cannot add TMarkerDescriptor like this:

```
MapView1.AddMarker(MyMarker1);  // MyMarker is a TMapMarkerDescriptor
```

You must use a TMapMarker like this:

```
MMyMarker1 := MapView1.AddMarker(MyMarker1); // MMyMarker1 is a TMapMarker and MyMarker1 is a TMapMarkerDescriptor
```

However, you must use:

```
MMyMarker1.DisposeOf;
```

on `OnFormClose` for every marker you add to the map to avoid crash, like this:

```
procedure TForm69.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
try
MMyMarker1.DisposeOf;
finally
 Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
end;
```